# Подсчёт количества отриц. чисел. из k введённых любых чисел

Tags: c#

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите количество чисел:");
int kolvo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int[] a = new int[kolvo];
for (int c = 0; c < a.Length;c++)
{
    a[c] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}

for(int c1 = 0; c1 < a.Length; c1++)
{
    if(a[c1] < 0)
    {
        int kol = 0;
        kol++;
        Console.Write(kol);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("\n"+"конец.");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Я почти сделал, только вместо кол-ва одним числом мне выдаёт единички. Например если отриц. чисел код нашёл 5, то вывод будет в виде:11111. Дальше не хватает мозгов простую арифм. операцию сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Вы создаётся переменную `kol` увеличивает, выводите и на следующей итерации снова его обнуляете. Вам надо создание переменной вынести до цикла, а вывод после цикла

```
int kol = 0;
for(int c1 = 0; c1 < a.Length; c1++)
        {
            if(a[c1] < 0)
            {
                kol++;
            }
        }
Console.Write(kol);
```